# What password and username do I use for mysql_connect()?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Okay so as you will probably be able to tell but, I am pretty new to MySQL and PHP and I have ran into a problem.. In my `connect.php`, which connects to the server, I don't know if my password and username along with the port are right. Now the reason it says port 8080 is because one of my other web development programs was using port 80 so I went in to the Apache files and changed to port, so now when I log into phpMyAdmin I have to type `localhost:8080`. I don't know if that has to do with `mysql_connect`, also I checked on phpMyAdmin and it says my username is `root` and my password is empty. Does the empty password mess with `MySQL_connect()`? Thanks, here's the code:

`connect.php`:

```
<?php 
//This file allows me to easily connect to my database

mysql_connect("localhost:8080", "root", "");//connects to database, params are ("servername", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("membersystem");//selects the table from db
?>
```

`login.php`:

```
<?php 
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);//saves us from getting undefined index error

session_start();//makes it a sesion based system
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>

</head>

<body>
     <!--the action='./login.php' tells the page where its gonna send the info, and the method='post' makes it so it dosent show the users personal info -->
    <?php 
        $form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='user'/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login'/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>";

        if($_POST['loginbtn']){//if loginbtn pressed
                $user = $_POST['user'];//gets the username from text field from the form above
                $password = $_POST['password'];//gets the password from text field from the form above

                if($user){//checks if the username field from the form has been filled out
                    if($password){//checks if the password field from the form has been filled out
                        require("connect.php");//connects to db through connect.php

                        $password = md5(md5("gshgrYY665f".$password."gr76TH967G"));//encrypts the password 

                        //echo "$password"; echos the hash for password (5f8b1a8d8f2471a2c7c17e0058873447 )

                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' ");//checks if the username is found in database
                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                        if($numrows == 1){
                                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);//gets the query associated with the php
                                $dbid = $row['id'];//gets the id from db
                                $dbuser = $row['username'];//gets the username from db
                                $dbpass = $row['password'];//gets the password from db
                                $dbactive= $row['active'];//gets the active value from db

                            if($password == $dbpass){
                                if($dbactive == 1){

                                        //sets session info
                                        $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                                        $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;

                                        echo "you have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b>. <a href='./member.php'>Click here</a> to go to member page";
                                    }
                                    else
                                        echo "You must activate your account to login. $form";



                                }
                                else
                                    echo "You didnt enter the right pass. $form";   
                            }
                            else
                                echo "The username you entered was not found. $form";

                        mysql_close();//closes connection
                    }
                    else
                        echo "You must enter your password. $form";
                }
                else
                    echo "You must enter your username. $form";
            }
            else
                echo $form;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: You shouldn't be using port 8080. That's the webserver's port, it's not the MySQL server's port.

Comment: Then what do i use instead? And im using mysql 5.6.17 and php 5.5.12 and apache 2.49.

Comment: First of all use `mysqli_*` function as `mysql_*` is deprecated and yes you can use empty password.

Comment: Whats port do i use? And do i have to change to port 8080 back to a different one in the config or just change it in connect.php?? @Barmar

Comment: Just use `localhost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use `8080` simply use `localhost` because that port number is not related to mysql but related to webserver. Inorder to address the webserver only you need to use it like `localhost:8080/project-name/`

And dont use `mysql_*` methods. will get disappointed in future. Use `mysqli`

```
 $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","membersystem") or die('Connection failed');
 $result = $con->query("Your query here");
```

or else you can use the same in procedural method with `mysqli_*` functions. But i prefer to go along with object oriented php.

Refer the documentation.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1):

Make connection like

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","membersystem");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

and w3schools link is http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp